# how to convert byte[] into BitmapFrame c#

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmapframe

I have tryed this but have exception - Operation is not valide due to current state of the object

```
private BitmapFrame backconvertor(byte[] incomingBuffer)
    {
        BitmapImage bmpImage = new BitmapImage();
        MemoryStream mystream = new MemoryStream(incomingBuffer);
        bmpImage.StreamSource = mystream;
        BitmapFrame bf = BitmapFrame.Create(bmpImage);
        return bf;
    }
```

Error rising when I am trying to

```
return backconvertor(buff);
```

in other function (buff - is ready!)

Comment: Which line throws the Exception?

Comment: BitmapFrame bf = BitmapFrame.Create(bmpImage);

Comment: take a look at here http://imagetools.codeplex.com/

Comment: no. there is a library and I need only ONE function byte[]-> BitmapFrame

Answer (score 2):

Documentation indicates that in order to initialize the image, you need to do it between `BeginInit` and `EndInit`. That is:

```
bmpImage.BeginInit();
bmpImage.StreamSource = mystream;
bmpImage.EndInit();
```

Or, you can pass the stream to the constructor:

```
bmpImage = new BitmapImage(mystream);
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.begininit.aspx for an example and more discussion of `BeginInit`.

Comment: still error(( "No imaging component for this operation found" in bmpImage.EndInit(); line

Comment: @curiousity: Of course it does not work if you use `CopyPixels`, that method does not copy any meta-information which is expected by `BitmapImage`. `BitmapImage` expects a fully encoded stream, with file format header.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have in a WPF Converter to handle byte to BitmapFrame and it works perfectly:

```
            var imgBytes = value as byte[];
            if (imgBytes == null)
                return null;
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(imgBytes))
            {
                return BitmapFrame.Create(stream,
                    BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
            }
```

Also its thread safe as I have used it in Task.Run before also.